# Cakephp using Set::extract to get partial match values

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there a way to extract using regex to extract values containing ".html" in below array?

```
    Array
    (
        [urlset] => Array
            (
                [url] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [loc] => http://www.abc.com.au/computers
                                [lastmod] => 2012-12-02
                                [changefreq] => daily
                                [priority] => 0.5
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [loc] => http://www.abc.com.au/hp-scanjet-5590-digital-flatbed-scanner.html
                                [lastmod] => 2012-12-02
                                [changefreq] => daily
                                [priority] => 1.0
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [loc] => http://www.abc.com.au/stock-wardrobe-dark-walnut-doors.html
                                [lastmod] => 2012-12-02
                                [changefreq] => daily
                                [priority] => 1.0
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [loc] => http://www.abc.com.au/stock-wardrobe-white-mirror-door.html
                                [lastmod] => 2012-12-02
                                [changefreq] => daily
                                [priority] => 1.0
                            )
                     )
               )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is likely no reason you should use regex to search the array. (and it would be more difficult than many other ways).

If you want to search through the array for '.html', just build a simple [php foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and use [PHP's array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to check for whatever text you're looking for.